# rgba(0,0,0,0.001) not working but rgba(0,0,0,0.002) works

Tags: javascript, canvas

Values under 0.002 turns transparent in rgba and ctx.globalAlpha when applied to canvas.

Any ideas why and how to go around this?

Test 1 with rgba 0.002 and 0.001:

[image]

[image]

Test 2 with rgba 0.003 and 0.002:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, you realize that `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.001)` is asking for something that's **one one-thousandth** opaque, right? I'm not surprised if any particular implementation calls that fully transparent.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am very aware of that. I am creating a pixel animation in canvas and I truly want this kind of opacity for creating a gradient effect that floats across the canvas (hard to explain the project idea). New canvas drawings are being drawn on top of each other, so even 0.002 opacity is a bit strong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pixel values are usually out of 255; 0.001 * 255 is 0.255 which is rounded to 0, while 0.002 * 255 is 0.51 which is rounded to 1.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know any workarounds for applying pixel values with transparency lower than 0.002?

Comment: That is definetly not pixel value, also the colors are in range of 0 to 255, opacity is between 0 and 1.

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu Perhaps the 0-1 value is calculated to 0-255 in Javascript just for clarity in the code?

Comment: Ultimately, they (usually) end up as integer values, usually from 0 to 255, representing values between 0.0 and 1.0. What integer values do you want?

Comment: @SimenL - No, there's no reason to believe that's the case.

Comment: @SimenL - Yeah, the 0.0-1.0 value is converted to 0-255 somewhere along the line; partly for convenience, partly because future hardware and/or some image formats can have finer resolution in the alpha value, and then it'll need to be converted to 0-65535.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/alpha-value

Comment: @sabik As low as it can possibly go, say 0.0001. It seems it turns completely transparent at values under 0.002. The difference between 0.002 and 0.001 is insane, so there must be some kind of limitation that I cannot get around.

Comment: 0.001 is equal to 0 whereas 0.002 is equal to 0.004 after calculation, you can check this in dev tools, it's probably because of how floating point numbers are handled in binary format in the browser engine.

Comment: It's certainly possible that in some implementations (possibly even several widespread ones), the alpha channel value is being mapped to an 8-bit value, and thus 255 * 0.001 is 0.255 which is then rounded to 0 where 255 * 0.002 is 0.51 which is rounded to 1, but I wouldn't assert that in the general case, there's plenty of 16-bit and 32-bit graphics handling out there. Fundamentally, Simen is just hitting a limit. (But calling it a pixel value is flatly incorrect.)

Comment: Yeah, hence the "usually". If 0.002 is non-zero and 0.001 is zero, the limit in this case is almost certainly that it gets converted to an 8-bit value, 0-255.

Comment: As for workarounds, @SimenL - that depends on your purpose. A practical method would be to scale the calculated values so that instead of being from 0 to 1.0 they're from 0.004 to 1.0; this would have the virtue of working on most hardware and software combinations, albeit not using the full dynamic range on high-end ones. If you only need it to work in limited contexts, you could try switching to 16-bit or 32-bit graphics; then you'd have the full range, but it'd only work for some hardware and software combinations and appear transparent with others.

Comment: Perhaps I will reduce the stepping/spacing to prevent the pixels from becoming to opaque so that most devices can run the simulation. I will put the min value to 0.004 and make sure it does not go below that in the calculations. Thanks for your help sabik! I edited the post with a couple examples @sabik